# Deploy a Docker environment on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, elastic-beanstalk

I just "Dockerized" my infrastructure into containers. The environment basically is one *nginx-php-fpm* container which contains nginx configured with php-fpm. This container connects to multiple data-containers which contains the application files for the specific component.

I've seen multiple talks on deploying a single container to Beanstalk, but I'm not sure how I would deploy an environment like this. Locally the environment works. I got my nginx-php-fpm container using the `--volumes-from` flag to a data-container.

How would I create the same environment on Beanstalk? I can't find the option to volume from another container. Also is there a good platform that handles the Docker orchestration yet?

Comment: I would create build images and copy the data from local into image, then just have that deployed.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Elastic Beanstalk provides [Multiple Docker environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html). It will be deployed on top of [AWS EC2 Container Service (ECS)](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/). ECS itself supports `--volume-from` options. See AWS ECS documentation [to mount volumes from another container using `volumesFrom`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_data_volumes.html#d0e4869).

AWS Elastic Beanstalk Multiple Docker environment use same `Dockerrun.aws.json` in ECS. Try to replicate the `Dockerrun.aws.json` from the ECS documentation.